# Получить изображение с html WebBrowser c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени форумчане. У меня есть вопрос. Как получить изображение со страницы загруженной через `WebBrowser`? Url изображения статический, но изображение генерируется скриптом, при каждом обращении с ссылке на изображение появляется другая. Как получит именно ту что появилась в самом контроле?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006825/converting-webbrowser-document-to-a-bitmap

Comment: @demonplus спасибо конечно, но одно дело сделать скриншот всей страницы или получить только изображение с нее

Comment: Ну так а вы знаете, в каком элементе DOM это изображение? Это Image или Canvas, код для получения элемента уже написан? В вопросе ничего про это нет. Тут скорее всего надо смотреть в сторону внедрения в страницу своего JS, который либо получает изображение с canvas через getImageData, либо рисует содержимое img в виртуальный canvas и далее делает предыдущий пункт. См. например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199842/240512

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight понял, картинка это капча Image.

Comment: `WebBrowser` устарел, используйте `WebView2` или `CefSharp`.

Comment: aepot спасибо понял, ну я понимал что придется использовать кастомный контрол браузера, но думал что получится и так(